# Preventing users from creating objects of certain classes in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a wrapper Python API for twitter,

For example:

```
search_tweets(**kwargs)
```

This API returns back a Tweet object. Tweet class looks something like:

```
class Tweet:
    def __init__(self, tweet, favorites, impressions, engagements, **kwargs):
        """ Create a new Tweet Object with field values """
        self.impressions = impressions
        self.favorites = favorites
        self.tweet = tweet
        self.engagements = engagements
        vars(self).update(kwargs)


    def retweet():
       """ Retweet this tweet """
```

Tweet object will be exposed to users because Tweet object will be returned by search_tweets API and users can call methods like retweet on this object, but I do not want users to explicitly create this object.

How can I denote that Tweet object should not be created by users, it should only be operated upon?

Comment: def __init__(self, tweet, favorites, impressions, engagements, do_i_know_what_im_doing, **kwargs): if do_i_know_what_im_doing !='yes_i_do': raise RuntimeError

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Tweet` class local to the function, for example:

```
def search_tweets(**kwargs):
    class Tweet:
        ...
```

So, the user can call `retweet()` and other methods on objects returned from `search_tweets()` function, but cannot easily create `Tweet` objects by hand due to the lack of human-readable name.
But the drawback of this approach is that it will be equally difficult to create `Tweet`s from other API functions.

Comment: Correct, with this approach it will be difficult to create Tweets from other API functions. I am sure if this is a very generic use-case and people would have thought multiple solutions for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the single underscore convention ([PEP documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)).

> _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

There is nothing "private" in Python, without having to jump through a bunch of hoops. The best thing you can do is follow convention and comment the class well.

Comment: _single_leading_underscore, I think this will give a wrong impression that the class in private? But users are still using methods on this class for example retweet()